# xlib ungrab_pointer - still can't "use" the pointer in other windows

Tags: python, linux, x11, python-2.x

I might have missunderstood my problem but I thought `display.ungrab_pointer` would release the semi exclusive right on the cursor.

After I start the following program, I won't be able to select text in any window. I can still click to set focus on the window but for instance, I can't mark text in FireFox or Sublime Text Editor.

**the desired result** would be that it doesn't "steal" the mouse at all, so I can use it while I record movements. From what I've learned, X11 simply copies and forwards the events to everyone who's registered as a listener, so I don't get why it would lock up the cursor the way it does.

```
import select
from time import time
from threading import *

from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib import X
from Xlib.ext.xtest import fake_input
from Xlib.ext import record
from Xlib.protocol import rq


def handle_event(event):
    print(event)
    return True

display = Display(':0')
ctx = display.record_create_context(
            0,
            [record.AllClients],
            [{
                    'core_requests': (0, 0),
                    'core_replies': (0, 0),
                    'ext_requests': (0, 0, 0, 0),
                    'ext_replies': (0, 0, 0, 0),
                    'delivered_events': (0, 0),
                    'device_events': (X.ButtonPressMask, X.ButtonReleaseMask),
                    'errors': (0, 0),
                    'client_started': False,
                    'client_died': False,
            }]
 )

class worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, display, ctx):
        self.display = display
        self.ctx = ctx
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        display.screen().root.grab_pointer(True, X.ButtonPressMask | X.ButtonReleaseMask, X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeAsync, 0, 0, X.CurrentTime)
        display.record_enable_context(self.ctx, handle_event)

        print 'Recieved exit.. ungrabing pointer'

handle = worker(display, ctx)

start = time()
while time()-start < 5:
    # Wait for display to send something, or a timeout of one second
    readable, w, e = select.select([display], [], [], 1)

    # if no files are ready to be read, it's an timeout
    if not readable:
        print('Got no events')
        break

    # if display is readable, handle as many events as have been recieved
    elif display in readable:
        i = display.pending_events()
        while i > 0:
            event = display.next_event()
            handle_event(event)
            i = i - 1

handle._Thread__stop()

display.record_free_context(ctx)
display.record_disable_context(ctx)
display.ungrab_pointer(X.CurrentTime)
display.flush()
```

Aside from this being a shitty way to terminate threads, what have I misunderstood?
I would think releasing the context and the `ungrab_pointer` would do the trick.

The program terminates as expected after 5 seconds, and does print out my events as it should. It's just that it doesn't "give back" the mouse cursor.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do and what exactly is happening. Do you get your mouse frozen even after your program exits? This is rather incredible.

Comment: @n.m Yes the mouse freezes in the sense that I can move it but not select anything inside windows (KDE). All the events get printed as they should but I lose functionality of the mouse. And yes even after my application has exited properly. I'm trying to print out Xevents without loosing functionality of the mouse completely hehe

Comment: If you grab the pointer, it **will** appear frozen to all other clients. That's the purpose of the grab. I have no idea why this situation continues after your client exits, but that's rather secondary. Grab is not the tool you need in the first place.

Comment: @n.m i will have another look as to how to record X events, see if I can solve it with another approach.